# Issue when Using Counter to count pairs Python

Tags: python-2.7

I took an online assessment where I was given the following question :

Input 1 : Integer - Length of the list

Input 2 : Integer List - Consists of different numbers

Output : Integer

Question : Find the total number of pairs possible from the list.

Example : 5, [10,23,2,10,23]

Since, 10 & 23 occurs twice, and 2 occurs only once, there are 2 pairs. So, result should be 2.

So, I did the following & I had one of the test cases failed. The test case wasn’t shown so I’m very confused as to where I went wrong. The code is :

```
dict=Counter(input2)
pairs=0
count=[]
for i in dict.values() :
        count.append(i)
for j in count :
        pairs+=j//2
return pairs
```

Except one test case, all the other 7 seems to satisfy. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by pairs?

Comment: For example, the list is [10,10,10,20,20,20,45,46,45]. 10 occurs 3 times, so 1 pair can be formed. 20 occurs thrice. So 1 pair can be formed again. 45 occurs twice, so again 1 pair can be formed. 46 occurs once, so 0 pairs. Total pairs = 1+1+1=3

Comment: @hiro-protagonist More than 1 pair will be formed for values more than 3.

Comment: @Hiro, I tried inputting the same number 4 times as well and I was able to get the correct expected output. For example if 10 occurs four times & 20 twice, it should still return 3 since 2 pairs of 10 and a pair of 20 is possible.

Comment: @rithwik-rajendran The code seems to work fine. Are you sure there wasn't any condition like "Return -1 in case of no pairs"?

Comment: Nope. Not at all. Had around 7 test cases. The first 6 worked while the 7th didn’t.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply divide the value of each entry of the dict that `collections.Counter` returns by 2:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [10,10,10,20,20,20,45,46,45]
print({k: v // 2 for k, v in Counter(l).items()})
```

This outputs:

```
{10: 1, 20: 1, 45: 1, 46: 0}
```

Or if you only want the total number of pairs:

```
print(sum(v // 2 for v in Counter(l).values()))
```

This outputs:

```
3
```

Comment: I get that mate but is there any problem in my code ? Should work fine isn’t  it ?

Comment: Yes it should work despite some redundant code. Do you have the test input that fails?

Comment: No. Apparently they didn’t give the test case that failed.